# laravel 5.2 entrust - show roles foreach user

Tags: laravel, roles, entrust

My controller is

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::paginate(15);

    return view('dash.users.index')->with(array('users' => $users));

}
```

in view i pass: `{{ $item->roles }}` and return all column as array, if i put `{{ $item->roles->get('name') }}`the table is blank, why?

I want to show user->roles->name foreach user

Answer (score 1):

If it's an array, you should only simply use this:

```
{{ $item->roles['name'] }}
```

Comment: i try, but throw me an error: **Undefined index: name**

Comment: @user0111001101, OK.
So, please make a var_dump in your blade file: <?php var_dump($item->roles); die(); ?>

Comment: @user0111001101, it's not the complete var_dump result. I need to know if it's an array or string. If it's a string, that means it's JSON and we could decode it

Comment: @user0111001101 try this: {{ $item->roles()->toArray()['name'] }} or {{ current($item->roles()->toArray())['name'] }}

Comment: @Mojtaba instead of going the long way via var_dump(); and then die(), you could just use dd(). That should save you a lot of typing ;)

Comment: @Pascal, for this particular case, I don't like the format of dd(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved with nested foreach! `@foreach($item->roles as $item) {{ $item['name'] }} @endforeach`

inside my `@foreach` user

Thank you Mojtaba for the help!